# Undo chown and chmod

Tags: linux, xampp, htdocs

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I ran the following commands to save files in htdocs folder (to conveniently use XAMPP for programming) without understanding its security consequences:

```
sudo chown username:groupname /opt/lampp/htdocs
sudo chmod 700 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

I would like to undo the file permissions (on the htdocs folder) to what it was before I ran the above commands.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no way undo chown and chmod. **But** you can see default permission of these folder in any other machine which has fresh installation or you can install lampp again in different folder. **Then** change chown and chmod permissions of /opt/lampp/htdocs to default.

Answer (score -3):

For the second one run this command

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

I solved the same problem by using this