# Ubuntu undo chown

Tags: ubuntu

I tried to change permissions for a specific folder in my Ubuntu `usr/lib`,
here is the command I typed:

`sudo chown -R myUserName ~/usr/lib`

Since then all the programs I try to run, like eclipse (I am guessing that all programs that are installed under lib folder) aren't running and my screen is jumpy. What to do to reverse/undo this change?

Comment: There isn't an undo. Always know what the permissions are before you make changes. Do you know who the owner of the folder was before you changed it? If this was /usr/lib then I would expect it to be root, but since it is in your home folder I would expect it to already be owned by you before hand. My Ubuntu system does not have this folder, but its a headless system and is out dated. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980581/undo-chown-and-chmod

Comment: the owner was root, I tried to change it back to root but still not working.